# Bootstrap model popup darken the screen BUT few part of screen still show on same level and not getting darkened

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

[image]

In an angular 7 project I am using a bootstrap model. When I open the model it only darkens **position: relative** components. Few components have **position: fixed** (see the screen shot). All other components have z-index: < 2; although it's not getting dark when O open model popup.

```
 <div class="modal fade" *ngIf="deleteDialogOpened" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"  role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header " >
            <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: left;">Are you sure you want to delete {{this.currentUser.firstName}}?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close('cancelDeleteDialog')">Cancel</button>
            <button class="submit-btn btn btn-elevate kt-login__btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close('delete')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the modal inside a div with the container class as follows:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="modal fade" *ngIf="deleteDialogOpened" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered"  role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header " >
            <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: left;">Are you sure you want to delete {{this.currentUser.firstName}}?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close('cancelDeleteDialog')">Cancel</button>
            <button class="submit-btn btn btn-elevate kt-login__btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="close('delete')">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create with New Version for 5.3 example
It support color mode and I try with jQuery
You can also make more options with drop down button :)
https://codepen.io/Anon-T/pen/WNKVpBz

With the HTML tag add `<html len='en' data-bs-theme='light'>`
create your button with JavaScript Switching